# Using Bootstrap on a website

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, themes

I want to use Bootstrap on a website.
But I don't really know what to do to start.

Is it better to find a Bootstrap theme first? The website on which I want to use Bootstrap  works fine actually but isn't responsive.

Comment: Did you read the Getting Started guide in bootstrap website? http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the regular [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) first, then write your own styles in CSS for customizing the look.

The Bootstrap documentation is quite detailled - you would usually find anything you need for starting there. In your case, you can start by reading the getting started guide.

You can get some free themes on several sites, such as [Bootswatch](http://bootswatch.com/).